# How to update Xcode git mark UI?

Tags: xcode, git

Xcode has git marks on editing files. It is obvious to know which file has changed.

[image: 111]

While I git committed, and the git mark UI still stays same.

```
➜ musicSheet git:(lu_yin) gst
On branch lu_yin
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/lu_yin'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

So is it a way to update Xcode git mark UI manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Source Control menu in Xcode has a menu item to refresh the source control status. In Xcode 11 choose Source Control > Fetch and Refresh Status. The menu item name may be different in earlier Xcode versions.